# Python Process pool executor shutdown on signal

Tags: python, supervisord, sys, concurrent.futures

I use supervisor to run some script like this. so when supervisor is stopped or interrupt, i try to gracefully exit from the script. This is my current code

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import os
import signal
import sys

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

some_flag = True

def some_func():
    while some_flag:
        executor.submit(print_some_num)

def print_some_num():
    print("From worker :{}".format(os.getpid()))
    print(random.randint(0,10))

def handler(arg1, arg2):
    print("Got interrupt")
    some_flag = False
    sys.exit("Run for ur life")
    #executor.shutdown(wait = False) ----> not working
    print("Shutdown")

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_func()
```

This works fine and now i am confused when i read about executor.shutdown(wait=True/False). So i tried that and i couldn't get the executor to shutdown (It just hangs). please help me out with these questions

```
 1) what does executor.shutdown do that sys.exit() doesn't do.
 2) What is advisable in production environment? If executor shutdown is required, please help me fix the issue with shutdown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Apparently, shutdown stops all the existing messages being processed, but sys.exit() just comes out. (in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

2) If somebody got stuck in the same place, use some global variable to signal shutdown.

```
def some_func():
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    while True:
        global some_flag
        print(some_flag)
        if not some_flag:
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            executor.submit(print_some_num)

def print_some_num():
    print("From worker :{}".format(os.getpid()))
    print(random.randint(0,10))

def handler(arg1, arg2):
    global some_flag
    print("Got interrupt")
    some_flag = False
    print("Shutdown")

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handler)
```